# C# Always Getting Empty Cookies

Tags: c#, winforms

So I always try to see any site cookies but i get empty string

```
var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
var client = new RestClient("https://server.com") {
    UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36",
};
client.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
var cookie = client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new 
Uri("https://server.com"));
MessageBox.Show("" + cookie);
```

Site Cookies

Comment: Did you try `client.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://server.com"));`I got that working in a project in the past

Answer (score 0):

You haven't sent any request to get cookie. Add `Execute` method call to your code

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
client.Execute(request); //add this line
var cookie = client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri("https://server.com"));
```